# Effectively solve optimization problem in this system?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, permutations, algorithms, computer-science

**The system :**
Given

- $2$ sets $I,J$ such that $I\cap J = \emptyset , \#I = \#J$
- a time-dependent function $c : \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \times I \times J \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ .

Consider a system that changes independently every unit time , say time $t-1$ and $t$  . The change is that  $$
\exists i\in I \forall j\in J (\;P(| c_t(i,j) - c_{t-1}(i,j) | > 0) > 0 \;)
$$
where P denotes probability . We'll know exactly which $i$ at time $t$ . Let's call this $i$ the key .

**The optimization problem:**
At each time $t$ we have full information of anything happened previously , and we need to solve the  optimization problem :

Find a one to one correspondence  $f : I \to J$ that minimizes $$
\sum_{i\in I} c_t(i,f(i))
$$

**My question:** Is there a way to effectively solve the optimization problem in this system ? (by effective I roughly refer to run-time and memory usage of algorithm .)

**Attempt :**

I visualize the system at a fixed time $t$ as a 3D plot ,  the z axis is $c_t$ , x axis is $I$ and y axis is $J$ . The solution space is all one to one correspondence lying on $x-y$ plane . The current system may differ from previous one by the the value of $c$ above a certain x value .

The best I could do is to avoid recomputing $c_t(i,f(i))$ for all $i$ that isn't the key .

However , it seems like we still need to search the whole solution space , which is all permutations of $I$ of size $\# I!$ .

I don't think other previous information is useful e.g. the previous solution to optimization , but I may have missed something .

Comment: Do we know the $c_t$, or only something about it's distribution? Do we know something about $c_t(i, j)$ if $i$ isn't key for $t$ (it seems that may be you imply it's the same as $c_{t - 1}(i, j)$, but not sure)? Anyway, for fixed point of time, if $c_t$ is known, your problem is exactly minimum weight perfect matching, that can be solved in $O(|I|^3)$.

Comment: @mihaild thank you for pointing out minimum weight perfect matching , I'm now learning it . I haven't done detailed analysis on $c_t$ and distribution yet , I'll do them after learning the matching algo . I'll come back if I find anything interesting .